# Balanced Binary Tree

Tags: binary-trees

Can someone please explain to me how the Wikipedia [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#cite_note-22#Types_of_binary_trees) on the left for a balanced binary tree is correct?

> One common balanced tree structure is a binary tree structure in which the left and right subtrees of every node differ in height by no more than 1

For node `ABCDE`, isn't the height of left subtree 2 and the height of the right subtree 0, making the difference of height 2?

**EDIT** As David rightly pointed out:

> That page defined "balanced" immediately above the example you're asking about, and it defines balanced in a different way to you.

I thought that the example was using the definition that comes immediately **after** the example, which I have quoted above. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I don't understand your question. That page defined "balanced" immediately above the example you're asking about, and it defines balanced in a different way to you. The tree you're asking about is balanced in the sense the page talks about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Wikipedia article is using a different definition of "balanced":

> A balanced binary tree has the minimum possible height.

Therefore, since a perfect binary tree of height $d$ has $2^{d}-1$ nodes, if a tree has $n$ nodes, the minimum possible height for that tree is $\left \lceil \log_2n \right \rceil$, and the tree you mention does indeed satisfy that condition.

Observe that the usual definition of "balanced tree" is in an asymptotic setting, i.e. depth is $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.